# Generating table names with same structure but different names

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I am creating a forex application.I want to create the same schema but create different tables with the same schema according to the currency pairs.I searched for this on google and here too.No case matches my requirement.I am using Flask_sqlalchemy for the database ORM and postgres as my database.

app/**init**.py

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_mongoengine import MongoEngine
from app.config import Config
from flask_restful import Api
from flask_jwt_extended import JWTManager
from flask_migrate import Migrate
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy



app=Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object(Config)
dbs=SQLAlchemy(app)
migrate=Migrate(db=dbs,app=app)
jwt=JWTManager(app)
db=MongoEngine(app)
api=Api(app)


from app import errors,models,resources


api.add_resource(resources.CourseListResource,'/api/v1.0/courses',endpoint="courses")
api.add_resource(resources.CourseResource,'/api/v1.0/courses/<string:name>',endpoint="course")
api.add_resource(resources.UserRegistration,'/api/v1.0/register')
api.add_resource(resources.UserLogin,'/api/v1.0/login')
api.add_resource(resources.UserLogoutAccess, '/api/v1.0/logout/access')
api.add_resource(resources.UserLogoutRefresh, '/api/v1.0/logout/refresh')
api.add_resource(resources.TokenRefresh, '/api/v1.0/token/refresh')
```

app/config.py

```
import os

class Config():
    SECRET_KEY = os.environ.get('SECRET_KEY') or 'mysecretkey'
    MONGODB_SETTINGS = {"DB": "pmong"}
    SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = os.environ.get('DATABASE_URL') or "postgresql://localhost/test"
    #sqlite_db_path=sqlite:///" + os.path.join(basedir, 'app.db')
    SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS = False
```

app/models.py

```
from app import dbs
class Forex(dbs.Model):


    id = dbs.Column(dbs.Integer, primary_key=True)
    time = dbs.Column(dbs.DateTime, unique=True, nullable=False)
    high = dbs.Column(dbs.Float, nullable=True)
    low=dbs.Column(dbs.Float,nullable=True)
    open=dbs.Column(dbs.Float,nullable=True)
    close=dbs.Column(dbs.Float,nullable=True)
    volume=dbs.Column(dbs.Integer,nullable=True)

    def save_to_db(self):
        dbs.session.add(self)
        dbs.session.commit()
```

Currently I have not given the table name.I should be able to create different table name for this schema and manipulate it as well.I cannot find a way to create dynamic tables for each currency pair.

Comment: Could you give an example of what you are trying to achieve? From what I understand you want to have multiple `Forex` tables following the same schema but why not simply adding `currency_from` and `currency_to` in that table?

Comment: I cannot do that as the dataset will be huge.Thus for each currency pair I want to maintain a different table.I think searching through the table will be very difficult as there will be datapoint for each second.This way I can maintain the historical data for particular currency pair in a table which I think will be easier and faster when searching.

Comment: And do you know the pairs of currency in advance or does it have to be completely dynamic?

Comment: It should be completely dynamic.I am trying to make create it using function but I thought there should be an easier way to do it.